Linear model with nested random effects
I'm having trouble understanding how to specify my statistical model in the R function lme4::lmer to perform a mixed linear model with nested data.
My data set has two columns for independent variables. One is the "design" which is a factor with two levels, "control" and "experiment". The other independent variable is "line_number", which groups sets of samples. A short dataframe is given below as an example for illustrative purposes.
The "design" variable is a factor in my model because I want to measure the effect of "experiment" over "control". Additionally, "line_number" is a random effect, and I am interested in measuring the variance between control lines, and between experimental lines. This is, I would expect to get two variance estimates, one for differences between control lines, and another for differences between experimental lines.
I would have expected for this to work with:
lme4::lmer(data = df, response ~ design + (1|design:line_number))

but nesting this way does not seem to work (or only gives one between-groups variance). I also tried creating separate variables for control and experimental lines, filling with NAs where necessary:
lme4::lmer(data = df, response ~ design + (1|line_control) + (1|line_experiment))

But this gives error.
I appreciate any help with this problem. I fear I am having some fundamental misunderstanding here calculating variances between control and between experimental samples.
Example of data frame structure:
df <- tibble(response = rnorm(12),
             design = rep(c("control", "experiment"), each = 6),
             line_number = rep(rep(c("l_1","l_2","l_3"), each = 2), times = 2),
             line_control = ifelse(design == "control", line_number, NA),
             line_experiment = ifelse(design == "experiment", line_number, NA))


First of all, it's not feasible to use variables with only two levels (such as design) as random effect grouping variables. Second, in your first model, you have specified design as both a fixed predictor and a random effect grouping variable. You can't do that because they use up the same variance. Third, the line_control and line_experiment variables are fully confounded with "design" which is why you get the error.
Doesn't
library(lme4)
model<-lmer(response ~ design + (1|line_number), data=data)

work?

Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, that does not work for me. This code calculate the effect on "design" (which I want). However, regarding the variance estimated by "line_number" as a random effect, what this gives is the variance between lines, all of them. What I need is an estimate of variance between control lines, AND an estimate of variances between experimental lines.

Well, then I guess you can try m<-lmer(response ~ (1|design) + (1|line_number), data=data), but variance estimates tend to be unreliable when you have less than 5 grouping levels.

"What I need is an estimate of variance between control lines, AND an estimate of variances between experimental lines" this is, in my understanding, impossible with your data. You can only get an estimate of how much variance in response is attributable to the grouping of design vs. control. Not separate estimates for variance for design and variance for control.
